# Adding GD file resize and rename to php image upload script

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have this script which allows a picture to be uploaded and then a pointer is stored in a DB to the file on the file system. I got this script from another StackOverflow question and it does pretty much everything I need except for 2 things.
The first thing I need is to be able to resize the images and the second part I've just read about is to rename the file to prevent user errors etc.

Here is the upload file that takes the form data from the user input form and writes the data to DB and the picture to the images dir.

```
 <?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "your directory";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['nameMember'];
$bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$about=$_POST['aboutMember'];
$bands=$_POST['otherBands'];


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("yourhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("dbName") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (nameMember,bandMember,photo,aboutMember,otherBands)
VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic', '$about', '$bands')") ;

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: please, please, learn about prepared statements and bound variables.  As it stands your script is open to "SQL Injection" exploits.

Comment: Just be aware that without using mysql_real_escape_string, your code is horribly insecure. You only need to change the lines like $name=$_POST['nameMember'];  to $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameMember']); to go a long way to making it more secure.

Comment: Well I am still learning php and mysql and this was a task I set for myself. I learn best by working with examples. 
Ive found usability problems with this script since I posted, for example it doesn't limit the file types to .gif, .jpg and .png files.
However it does show me how to stick the file reference into a DB

Answer (score 0):

For resizing, here is an article explaining resizing images to any arbitrary size using GD. It has options for cropping or letter boxing to fit the destination aspect ratio.

http://www.spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=1

For filenames, just rename the files to a random id, and make sure you are not already using that id.

```
do {
    $filename = uniqid().'jpg';
} while (file_exists('image/path/'.$filename);
```